# Dangers of putting a gem into a gemfile is someone trying to install it doesn't support the gem?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

If I have some coworkers that have an old version of Mac OS X that doesn't support the gem I want to use ([`terminal-notifier`](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier) specifically), are there dangers of putting this into the `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'terminal-notifier'
```

Is there some way to say that it requires OS X 10.8 or greater? What happens if someone on < 10.8 tries to install terminal-notifier? I'm on the latest os so I can't exactly test this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put into **[gemfile](/questions/tagged/gemfile)** the following condition:

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i
   version = `uname -r` =~ /^(\d+)\./ && $1.to_i
   gem 'terminal-notifier' if version >= 12
end
```

This should work. I know that in case of [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) 10.4 the `uname -r` was *8.x*, and of [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) 10.5 the `uname -r` was *9.x*.

Or with call to `sw_vers` app:

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/i
   version = `sw_vers -productVersion` =~ /^10\.(\d+)/ && $1.to_i
   gem 'terminal-notifier' if version >= 9
end
```

In case when the [gem](/questions/tagged/gem) is to be planned to run with [jruby](/questions/tagged/jruby) you have to use `rbconfig` module.

```
if RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /darwin|mac os/i
   version = `sw_vers -productVersion` =~ /^10\.(\d+)/ && $1.to_i
   gem 'terminal-notifier' if version >= 9
end
```

Comment: If you could't load the gem, please provide me result of your `uname -r`. I can't test the code.

Comment: Does not work for me (Mavericks) as `uname -r` returns `"13.0.0"`. I think that better approach is `\`sw_vers -productVersion\` >= '10.9'`

Comment: of course, `sw_vers -productVersion` would be better, but show your `RUBY_PLATFORM`

Comment: `"x86_64-darwin13.0"`

Comment: @majioa and mechanicalfish thanks! I'd still like to know what happens if you try to install a gem that your os doesn't support. Either of you know?

Comment: @Miles close the gem under the `if RUBY_PLATFORM` condition.

Comment: Beware of JRuby, it will always display `java` as `RUBY_PLATFORM`. I believe you can use `require 'rbconfig'; RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']` instead.

Comment: @Miles it depends on the gem. If it needs to be compiled, it may crash during installation and things like bundle install won't work. If it's precompiled (like terminal-notifier) or pure Ruby it will probably install successfully but won't work properly or at all.

Comment: @majioa I ended up not using this because while I'm developing on a Mac, I'm deploying to an unix box. When I use cap to deploy it notices its gemfile.lock is different than the one in the repo, so rolls back the deploy.